# How to whitelist all connections in MySQL

Tags: mysql

It would be convenient for me to whitelist a server so that anyone with the username and password can connect to it remotely? Is this possible? I do understand this is horrible for security purposes if it's even possible (I haven't found anything that mentions a way to do such.)

Answer (score 1):

This should be easily achieved by issuing the command:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to user@'%'; -- you can also use dbname.* to restrict their 
                              -- access to a given database.
```

as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236000/allow-all-remote-connections-mysql) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348506/grant-remote-access-of-mysql-database-from-any-ip-address).

You can do some restricting (normally a good idea) by making use of the wildcard (% is the MySQL wildcard) - you can also do '%.domain.com' or '%.123.123.123' or similar if necessary.

You don't have to `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES` - you could just give them `SELECT` and/or `UPDATE` for example and not `INSERT`... This is all explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html).

Comment: Do you need to explicitly specify the user's password?

Comment: Just ran `mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* to user@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (2.66 sec)
mysql>` and it worked fine - so, no, you don't need to specify a password. You may have to issue a "flush privileges" command for this to take effect. Also, check out the documentation in my first link, especially [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10236195/470530) - the bit about specifying a local user also.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Still get the 10061 error I was having before I added whitelisting. (In particular I created a new user both locally and white-listed for remote. My hosting providers tell me the firewalls are just fine, so it's not that.) @Vérace

Comment: Did you also specify a local user as mentioned in the post to which I linked?

Comment: @Vérace using a whildcard (%) is not safe at all since thats mean your database is opened to all, if you use 10.10.10.% that will be safer( that mean if you working with a company all users will have access to MySQL if they now the password since you wildcard network class C. but if you wildcard the first number its mean your may connect to your database server even outside the network, whats need to be done since it will provide more secure access to ask users (that need access to the server) to provide their IP address, and create users based on it

Comment: I know this - that's why I gave the OP two other options - i.e. `GRANT`ing a reduced set of privileges and/or using the wildcard (%) as you mentioned - your point is well taken though - but what the OP asked for, I also provided. Plus, the OP has shown that he knows the risks "this is horrible for security purposes...".

Comment: I did specify a 'user'@'localhost'. Having an open connection from anywhere is what I need because we need to be able to work from anywhere on our dev server. (Not like we have a designated office or something.)

Comment: Can you ping the server from external machines? Check the port - 3306? Is this open to the outside? It appears that what I've given you is MySQL accepted practice - maybe it's time to investigate the firewall/networking side of things? Also, try (since it's a dev machine), flushing privileges and rebooting the server. Connect to the mysql server as "user" and run "show grants" - see what the server thinks they can do?